# Dual CPU in HP Proliant ML350p Gen8 with 430 watt PSU?

Tags: power-supply, xeon, hp-proliant

I have a HP Proliant ML350 Gen8 server with a single Xeon E5-2609 CPU and would like to upgrade it to something faster. But is the PSU large enough for dual CPU's? The 430 watt mine has is the smallest of the 3 different power supplies the server comes with.

I don't have any other hardware in the server, except a single SSD and 6x 4 gb RAM modules.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** 460 watt PSU's will work fine with 2 x 2609 CPU's.
I'm running 2 x 2609 CPU's 128Gb RAM and P830 Array Controller with 16 x 300GB 15K 12G SAS disks with no problems.